# iMacros and the Back Command?

Tags: testing, imacros

I'm making my first (admittedly bad) macro with imacros and have ran into a reoccurring issue with the BACK command not working as it seems like it should.

```
TAG POS=8 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:name&&TXT:*
WAIT SECONDS=5
'Extracting stuff 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=h1 ATTR=itemprop:name&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=span ATTR=itemprop:name&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
BACK
TAG POS=9 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:name&&TXT:*
```

The problem is that sometimes the BACK command will fail (for no obvious reason) and then the macro will stop working since it can't find the next tag. I have to manually navigate back to the page (pausing it and pressing back won't work) and then resume the macro.

Is this a known issue? Any way to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put a `WAIT` command after BACK or to increase the `SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE`. I've also noticed that Imacros is kind of groggy with where it is, so it is always better to specify `TAB T=...` often, so he would know it is on the same page. I hope this helps.